# why do I see a compile time error for the below?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to do a simple program, adding a node to the end of the link list:

```
/*Insert Node at the end of a linked list 
  head pointer input could be NULL as well for empty list

Node is defined as 
  struct Node
  {
     int data;
     struct Node *next;
  }
*/

Node* Insert(Node *head,int data)
{

    if(head){
         Node *curr_node=head;

        while(curr_node->next)
            curr_node=curr_node->next;
    }

    Node *new_node=(Node *)calloc(1,sizeof(Node));
    new_node->data=data;
    new_node->next=NULL;

    if(head)
            curr_node->next=new_node;
    else
            head=new_node;

    return head;
}

/* the main function calls it*/
```

when I compile, I see the following error:

In function ‘Node* Insert(Node*, int)’:
solution.cc:59:13: error: ‘curr_node’ was not declared in this scope
             curr_node->next=new_node

why does it say curr_node not declared, when it's actually declared right in the beginning. What am I missing here?

Comment: `curr_node` is only declared inside the `if`-block

Comment: And btw, there is no `Node`, only `struct Node`. Next time, try posting a *real*,  [minimal, **complete**, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: The compiler did not say "not declared", it said *"in this scope"*.

Comment: yes shouldn't it be taken into consideration only when head exists?? why would the program crib about it if  there's no head i.e empty linked list ??

Comment: Because in that case `curr_node` is not defined *at all*. Your question says "it's actually declared right in the beginning" but it is not. The conditional test is first.

Comment: Or, just skip both `if` tests, use a pointer to pointer, and [cut the code size in half](http://pastebin.com/pzhAD8fa).

Comment: just because nobody has mentioned it yet: Please don't cast the return of `malloc` & co

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I was going through your comment and referring back to the question:[Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), where it mentions:void * is automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer type. However when I remove the type conversion, I see a compilation issue: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘Node*

Comment: Okay I figured it out , I was using a an editor set to c++ while doing this, and in c++ it's necessary to cast else it would throw an error

Comment: Curious:, why code `new_node=(Node *)calloc(...);` instead of `new_node=calloc(...);`  IOWs, what lesson/instructor suggested code cast the result of `malloc()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable declared in a function definition has a scope which extends only to the innermost `{}` braces.  So your variable `curr_node` is no longer valid after the first `if` block.

To fix this, declare your variable outside the `if` block:

```
Node* Insert(Node *head,int data)
{
    Node *curr_node = NULL;
    if(head){
        curr_node=head;

        while(curr_node->next)
            curr_node=curr_node->next;
    }
```

Comment: ooo gotcha!! I was under the impression that it's scope existed until the end of the function( never realized it was until the braces). Thanks!! :)